# Photoshop. Space glitches like in the game Quantum Break

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

So here's this glitch effect in a game called Quantum Break. Essentially, it breaks the space into lots of randomly generated polygons that you can say "warp the space behind them". You'd rather look at it. You can see the glitches on the image. First, you can see them left to the main character, little bit down the soilder. The sky and the big building in the front is also glitched. Also, the surroundings of the car to the left are somewhat glitched too.

Sure it's a 3d game, but, I guess one can do similar distortions in photoshop. I tried to make it myself. I took an image, duplicated it, then created lot's of different triangles and quadrilaterals. Then I grouped all of them, and clipped the duplicate layer onto the group. Then I tried different manipulations with the duplicate layer(i.e. scaling, distorting, rotating etc). I guess I had to spend some more time on that.. but anyways. I'd like to see the result of people who know their stuff.

By the way I also tried to look in the web on that, but to no avail. The game doesn't seem to be very popular.

[image: Here.]

Comment: I wasn't able to find a better screenshot, sorry.

Comment: What you have been doing seems to be exactly what I would do. Just add to your "thinking about viewing" that displacement is made (in the case of the game) generating picture from different angle than your main camera. So in the bacground pciture you nee to remove fragment of the object you gonna change position in the layer above.

Comment: I have *no clue* what you are referring to in that image. "glitch" describes nothing. At the very least **crop** the image to an area you are referring to.

Comment: @Scott I have to say, I'm similarly perplexed by this question. I don't see what the OP is referring to as a glitch?

Comment: To the OP, please try to find a better screen shot, or perhaps mark the areas which you see as a "glitch". Thanks.

Comment: Best I can *guess* is possibly the polygonal shapes in some areas which appear to be "shards" of the image .... sort of a deformation... which isn't some filter or "effect" for Photoshop.. it's a 3D thing where breaking meshes into polygons is much much easier.

Comment: @Scott Oh, OK I think I see it now. Will try to post an answer.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, I meant those polygonal deformations. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try to use a `Smudge Tool` with a torn-type tip, `Spacing` turned off, 100% `Strength` and high `Angle Jitter`:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you you are trying to make some kind of triangular shards, here's one possible method. For this to work I assume it's one flattened image layer, although it should also work with a Smart Object if you need non-destructive editing.

1. Create a new layer above the image layer and fill it white.
2. With the polygon select tool, draw some random triangles*. Fill some 50% grey, and some black.

Example

[image]

3. Ensure that the layer with triangles is switched on, and save the image somewhere you can find it easily, such as on your desktop, using the filename "displacement.psd" or another name you will remember.
4. Hide the triangle layer, and select the image layer
5. Do *Filters > Distort > Displace*
6. Set the vertical and horizontal scale to something like 10, click OK
7. When prompted navigate to the displacement.psd you saved earlier, click Open

Here's the result before and after

[image]

*Note: A variation on this could work by creating a custom triangle brush with random jitter to make the displacement map.